# Fragment inflates view twice after OnGlobalLayoutListener()

Tags: android, fragment, measure

I am using a Master/Detail flow in my app. The ItemDetailFragment inflates test_grid.xml. Because I wanted to make the views fit the fragment exactly, I inserted an OnGlobalLayoutListener() in onViewCreated to measure my frag and calculate the perfect sizes for the views.  So far so good, BUT the test_grid.xml from R.layout gets inflated with the default view sizes and then abruptly inflates my caculated sizes, which of course is not what I planned to happen.

I tried View.Gone in onViewCreated() for my rootView and for the Gridlayout as well, but was unable to make it visible gain. All of this trouble just to prevent to create the whole layout programmatically, which consists of 42 cells. It seemed like the better way to go, except that I cannot get passed this problem. Any suggestions?

test_grid.xml:

```
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/my_test_grid"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:columnCount="6"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:rowCount="7"
    android:visibility="visible"
     >

    <Space
        android:id="@+id/space_6"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_name"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
         />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_name"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        />
... more views...
       <Space
        android:id="@+id/space_35"
        android:layout_width="0dp" />
</GridLayout>
```

ItemDetailFragment.java:
    package com.example.ccc;

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.ViewTreeObserver;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.GridLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ItemDetailFragment extends Fragment {

    int fragmentWidth;
    int fragmentHeigth;
    int bestRowHeight;
    int bestSpaceWidth;
    int bestViewWidth;
    GridLayout mGrid;
    int view_show;

    public ItemDetailFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.test_grid, container,
                false);

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        final View rootView = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.my_test_grid);
        // mGrid = (GridLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.my_test_grid);
        // mGrid.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        rootView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
                new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

            @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
             rootView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);

                 fragmentHeigth = rootView.getHeight();
                 fragmentWidth = rootView.getWidth();
                 bestRowHeight = fragmentHeigth / 7;
             bestSpaceWidth = (fragmentWidth / 100) * 10;
             bestViewWidth = (fragmentWidth / 100) * 20;

                // change views here!!!
                View sp6 = rootView.findViewById(R.id.space_6);
                ((GridLayout) rootView).removeView(sp6);
                View sp35 = rootView.findViewById(R.id.space_35);
                ((GridLayout) rootView).removeView(sp35);
                setRowsHeight(sp6, bestRowHeight);
                setColsWidth(sp35, bestSpaceWidth);
                ((GridLayout) rootView).addView(sp6, 5);
                // mGrid = (GridLayout)
                // rootView.findViewById(R.id.my_test_grid);
                // mGrid.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
});

super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
// mGrid = (GridLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.my_test_grid);
// mGrid.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

}

    private void setColsWidth(View v, int width) {
        LayoutParams lp;
        lp = v.getLayoutParams();
        lp.width = width;
        v.setLayoutParams(lp);
    }

    private void setRowsHeight(View v, int height) {
        LayoutParams lp;
        lp = v.getLayoutParams();
        lp.height = height;
        v.setLayoutParams(lp);
    }

    public void setWidthHeight(View v, int width, int height) {
        LayoutParams lp;
        lp = v.getLayoutParams();
        lp.width = width;
        lp.height = height;
        v.setLayoutParams(lp);
    }

}
```

As you can see, I tried to make the view visible or gone at different spots of the code, but none were a workable solution.